# Simple Python number generation

Tags: python, numbers, sequence

I'm missing something very simple.  I'm a new Python student, so bear with me.

```
for i in range(10):    
    print("\n")
    for x in range(10):
        print(x, end = " ")
```

Sample output:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9    
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9    
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9    
...
```

The "`i`" variable is setting the size of what I want to output, and in the above example I am showing the range of 0-9, 10 times.  How would I alter this to display the following without using the print command by way of a string or an array?  I'm trying to use two nested "for" statements, but I'm drawing a blank on what to use in place of the range command.

Desired output:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1    
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2    
3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3    
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You are printing the variable from your inner loop (x) instead of the variable from the outer loop (i).  Do it this way:

```
for i in range(10):

    print("\n")
    for x in range(10):
        print(i, end = " ")
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick response!  That was exactly what I was overlooking!

Answer (score 0):

why to loop twice, we know `str*n` give n times str

```
>>> for x in range(10):
...     print((str(x) + ' ')*10)
... 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 
3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 
4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 
6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 
7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 
8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 
9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9
```

demo:

```
>>> 'a'*5
'aaaaa'
>>> 'a'*10
'aaaaaaaaaa'
>>> 'hello**'*10
'hello**hello**hello**hello**hello**hello**hello**hello**hello**hello**'
>>> '9'*10
'9999999999'
```

Answer (score 0):

This also works:

```
for i in range(10):
  print ' '.join(str(i) * 10)
```